# Sublime text 3 package to view JSON response like in Chrome network view

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

I want long JSON files to collapse in Sublime Text 3 like the Chrome network tab Preview section. Is there any Sublime Text package for this.

Something similar to following picture

[image: Chrome Network Tab preview section]

Answer (score 15):

Some of the answers here suggested `Pretty JSON`, but it didn't work for me. Although the installation was successful but still after pressing the shortcut key `[command + control + j]`, it didn't work for me. I double-checked the setting, everything was correct. I was using Sublime version `3.2.2` and my macOS version was `Catalina Version 10.15.3`. I also found a thread in Github where multiple people mentioned the same issue with Sublime version 3.

[image]

Added a screenshot of my settings for reference.

Even though `Pretty JSON`didn't work for me what worked for me was `HTML-CSS-JS Prettify`.

Following are the steps to install through Sublime Package Manager: 
 1. `Cmd+Shift+P` 
 2. type `install`, select `Package Control: Install Package` 
 3. type `prettify`, select `HTML-CSS-JS Prettify`

After installing it, for formatting the JSON text we need to use the shortcut key `[command + shift + h]`. That will format our JSON text.

**Note: HTML-CSS-JS Prettify requires NodeJS in your system to work.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: If we update the field to correct path it works even in case of Pretty JSON `"jq_binary": "/usr/local/Cellar/jq/1.6/bin/jq"`

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Pretty JSON](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pretty%20JSON). It is the best I have found to prettify and validade JSON codes.
But it won't give list indexes like chrome. At most you can fold those list itens folding by levels.

Comment: Yes Pretty JSON doesn't work like chrome preview, and I already tried this before posting this question. Is there any other editor apart from sublime which serves this purpose

Comment: Doesn't show up in the package manager of Sublime Text 4.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem: [Pretty JSON](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Pretty%20JSON) did not work for me (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and ST 3.2.2).
The alternative suggested by [Rito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5892553/rito), HTML-CSS-JS Prettify, requires NodeJS in your system to work.

Another alternative that *does not require NodeJS* which worked fine for me is the  [Pretty YAML](https://github.com/aukaost/SublimePrettyYAML) ST-plugin which uses PyYAML internally.

Install is analogous to Rito's comment (and detailed on the github page).

Use Alt+Ctrl+Y to prettify a selection (or whole file)